# php script for reading rss feed

Tags: php, rss, rss-reader

I am facing a problem with the RSS Reader. I have downloaded a php script from [fivefilters](http://fivefilters.org) to read RSS contents.

Now this script is not able to extract the content from the link given by RSS feeds because of old version of downloaded script. Other php scripts I have found are paid.

Can you please suggest any idea/tool/script/way to sort out this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try SimplePie: https://github.com/simplepie/simplepie

I dont know if this solves your particular problem, but i had good experiences with it.

Comment: Thank you @ivoba. but here my problem is to extract the content from article link. Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the RSS and point to element you want to extract?

Comment: This is not something related to any specific article. in general i am asking. i think because of some new changes (html or anything) in content pages it is creating problem.